# editText insert characters in response to typed values (time entry)

Tags: android

I want the user to enter the lunch time (4 numbers), but only using numbers. The ":" would be inserted in real time. Example: Inserted "0830" and "08:30" is displayed. I only found with "." and "," for monetary purposes. What is the best way to automatically and in realtime set the ":" between hour and minute? Thanks

XML :

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/lunch"
 android:hint="00:00"
 android:inputType="time"
 android:digits="0123456789:"
 android:maxLength="5"/>
```

Comment: I think a better user experience is to use a time picker, and then have a static TextView which gets updated with the time chosen in the exact format you want.

Comment: We don't have time specific input type for EditText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this:

```
vendorSearchEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            int length = 0;
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                String str = vendorSearchEt.getText().toString();
                length = str.length();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {               

                String str = vendorSearchEt.getText().toString();
                if(str.length()==2 && length <str.length()){//length check for backspace
                    vendorSearchEt.append(":");
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Could set the cursor after the colon too, right?

Comment: yes, it will be done automatically and for manual positioning use editText.setSelection(pass the index) and it will show the cursor to the desired position which is 3 in your case

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below code using textwatcher

```
TextWatcher textWatcherNumber = new TextWatcher() {
    boolean isEdging;

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {
        if (isEdging) return;
        isEdging = true;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(Common.parseOnlyNumbers(text.toString()));

        if (sb.length() > 2)
            sb.insert(2, ":");

        text.replace(0, text.length(), sb.toString());
        isEdging = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
};
//below is code of common class
public class Common {
    public static String parseOnlyNumbers(String text) {
    return text.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
    }
}
```

---- additional details ----

This way you can also limit user to add phone number in format **(012)-345-6789-0000**
you can replace below stringbuilder code in above function.

```
if (sb.length() > 0)
    sb.insert(0, "(");
if (sb.length() > 4)
    sb.insert(4, ")-");
if (sb.length() > 9)
    sb.insert(9, "-");
if (sb.length() > 14)
    sb.insert(14, "-");
```